# Naming convention for a partition of a family of sets satisfying some basic properties

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Given a set of elements $\Delta$ and a collection of subsets $\mathcal{V} \subseteq 2^{\Delta}$, let  $\mathscr P=\{\mathcal{V}_i\}_{i \in I}$ be a partition of $\mathcal V$ such that all the parts of $\mathscr P$ are mutually disjoint in their elements, i.e., $(\bigcup\mathcal{V}_i)\cap(\bigcup\mathcal{V}_j)=\emptyset$, for any distinct $i$ and $j$ in $I$, where $\bigcup \mathcal V_i$ is the union of all the sets contained in $\mathcal V_i$, i.e., $\bigcup \mathcal V_i = \bigcup_{S \in \mathcal V_i} S$.

For example, for $\mathcal V=\{\{1,2,3\},\{3,4,5\},\{6,7,8\}\}$

1. $\mathcal V_1=\{\{1,2,3\}\}$ and $\mathcal V_2=\{\{3,4,5\},\{6,7,8\}\}$ compose a partition of $\mathcal V$ that **does not** satisfy the property stated because $(\bigcup\mathcal{V}_1)\cap (\bigcup\mathcal{V}_2)=\{1,2,3\}\cap\{3,4,5,6,7,8\}=\{3\}$.
2. $\mathcal V_1=\{\{1,2,3\}, \{3,4,5\}\}$ and $\mathcal V_2=\{\{6,7,8\}\}$, on the other hand, compose a partition of $\mathcal V$ that **does** satisfy the property stated because $(\bigcup\mathcal{V}_1)\cap (\bigcup\mathcal{V}_2)=\{1,2,3,4,5\}\cap\{6,7,8\}=\emptyset$.

Is there a known name for such a type of partition $\mathscr P$?

Comment: I’m not aware of one. I’d simply call it a partition of $\mathscr{V}$ into collections with pairwise disjoint unions.

Comment: This is always a partition of partitions in a sense. If I take an $X\subseteq \Delta$, partition $X$, then partition all the elements of $X$, the set of partitions I end up with is of your desired form, and any family of your form can be reached this way. Beyond this I don't know of any name.